# D3 linegraph using JSON data from API

Tags: json, d3.js, request, linegraph

I am working on making a linegraph in D3 that displays data in JSON format that is retrieved from an API.

I found an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) line graph project on D3's website and it seems relatively straight forward. The main difference between the example and my project is that the example uses data from a local csv file instead of JSON from an API request.

```
// This needs to be changed to my API request
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

I changed the csv request part to this because I'm trying to load in my JSON from the API:

```
    d3.json(url).get(function(d) {
    for(var i = 0; i < d.Data.length; i++) {
      coinValue.push(d.Data[i].close);
      dates.push(convertUnixTime(d.Data[i].time));
    }
    return d;
  }, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

This isn't working. I'm confused about why there's a comma and then another function right after.

What is the proper way to make the exact same line graph but with a d3.json function/API request instead?

My JSON looks like this: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=ETH&tsym=USD&limit=2&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between [d3.csv](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#csv) and [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#json) is the ***accessor (2nd argument)***.

**d3.csv:** `d3.csv(url[[, row], callback])` in which `row` is nothing but each row of the data fetched i.e. if you add a function as follows:

`d3.csv(url, function(d) { 
    // each row of the data
}, callback)`

**d3.json:** `d3.json(url[, callback])` DOES NOT provide this *each row* **accessor**. But you can do that within the callback as follows:

`d3.json(url, function(err, data) { 
   data.forEach(function(row) { 
       // parse each row as required
   });
})`

Using the above syntax along with the provided example code and JSON URL, here's a code snippet drawing a line chart:

```js
// This needs to be changed to my API request
d3.json("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=ETH&tsym=USD&limit=2&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG", function(error, d) {

 var data = d.Data;
  data.forEach(function(d){ d.time = new Date(d.time * 1000) });
  
  //console.log(data);
  if (error) throw error;

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .rangeRound([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
      
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Hope this helps.